# i am try to add ad to my app but my app have a erre

Tags: java, android, android-layout, adsense

I am trying to add AD by banner and Interstitial to the android studio
there is a err that what I don't know how to fix

mane XML here i set banner 
view for AD

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/bannerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-4200825572816870/9282311734">

    </com.google.android.gms.ads.doubleclick.PublisherAdView>


</LinearLayout>
```

mane java here I set codes 
from one in youtube

```
package com.example.android.lahga;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.InterstitialAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   InterstitialAd interstitialAd;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        AdView adView = (AdView) findViewById(R.id.bannerView);

        MobileAds.initialize( this,"ca-app-pub-4200825572816870~8543945136");
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);


        interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this);
        interstitialAd.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-4200825572816870/3511110306");
        interstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build() );
        interstitialAd.show();

    }
}
```

manifest
here I set permission
 for internet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.lahga">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="lahga"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="false"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP"
                android:value="true"/>


            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

app
here I take from
 google library

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.lahga"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.2.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.1.1'
}
```

I want to show me the ad but the app crashed

### **err massage in debage**

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.android.lahga, PID: 27710
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider: java.lang.IllegalStateException:

```
******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6781)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6672)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2000(ActivityThread.java:273)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2011)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:112)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:216)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7593)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:524)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:987)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: 

******************************************************************************
* The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized incorrectly. AdMob publishers    *
* should follow the instructions here:                                       *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-android-update-manifest         *
* to add a valid App ID inside the AndroidManifest.                          *
* Google Ad Manager publishers should follow instructions here:              *
* https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-android-update-manifest.   *
******************************************************************************


    at com.google.android.gms.internal.ads.zzxb.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:27)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAdsInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite@@18.1.1:3)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:7241)
        ... 10 more
```

--

Comment: What you observe other than a crash? Any error visible in screen or something? And what steps to reproduce the crash?

Comment: My application. It does not work at all. The screen opens and closes at the same time